# Приведение базового класса к наследуемому c#

Tags: c#, наследование

```
public class Product
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string supplierId { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Pack : Product
{
    public double width { get; set; }
    ....
}

private void Method(int val)
{            
        Product product = Class2.GetProduct(val);

        Pack item = (Pack)product ???
        item.width = 0.1D;
 }
```

Как сделать такое приведение не присваивая все атрибуты Product для Pack?

Comment: Кратко: никак!.

Comment: А какой _реальный_ тип объекта, возвращаемого вызовом `Class2.GetProduct(val)`?

Comment: Возвращается Product

Comment: Вариант 2 - Можно через рефлексию - проверять есть ли свойство/поле в обеих классах - и копировать его.

Comment: Задача к объекту Product добавлять различные атрибуты заранее не известные. Pack item = (Pack)product ругается на приведение. Product является базовым классом, а Pack производным.

Comment: Зачем такое извращение? Какую задачу вы хотите этим решить?

Comment: Есть библиотека, в которой описан Product 100500 атрибутами.Подключается к разным проектам, в которых добавляются различные свойства. Сам Product как свойство не использовать.

Comment: Может вам лучше хранить `Product` как свойство у `Pack` и через это свойство работать например `item.Product.id`? Не совсем понимаю почему вы так не хотите.

Comment: Как свойство его использовать нельзя.Все свойства `Product` не должны быть вложены...

Comment: Интересно, кому было очень скучно наплодить 100500 атрибутов, и не будет ли подвисать студия часто и надолго.

Comment: Ещё раз повторюсь, пишите `Pack item = (Pack)product;` и ваша проблема решена - вы можете заполнить все недостающие свойства  product которыми обладает Pack (т.е. кроме width ). Или вам нужно что-то другое?

Comment: `System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "Product" к типу "Pack"."`

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону AutoMapper и конструировать объект на основе `Product`

Comment: Тогда у вас пути: template, reflection, marshal

Comment: Самый простой возможно reflection. Template в чистом виде - врядли.

Answer (score 0):

Если в product не хранится объект Pack, то приведением типов вы не получите Pack. Если я все правильно понял,  вы немного не понимаете полиморфизм.  Вот ссылка: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.11.php почитайте про нисходящие преобразования.

Comment: Букварь читали, но есть задача. Хотелось бы решение задачи, пока пробую рефлексией.

Answer (score 0):

Привести объект класса `Product` к классу `Pack` нельзя - просто потому, что операция приведения подразумевает, что объект уже является объектом целевого типа, и просто позволяет вам получить ссылку на него как на объект целевого типа.

Т.е. код вида

```
Product original = ...;
Pack pack = (Pack)original;
```

подразумевает, что в этих "..." был создан именно объект типа `Pack`, просто на уровне кода, по какой-то причине, ссылка на него попала в переменную типа Product.

Поменять тип уже созданного объекта нельзя. Что бы вы не делали с объектом типа не-Pack, он не станет объектом типа Pack. Чисто технически, объект - это кусок памяти в куче + заголовок, в котором лежит указатель на тип. После него и перед ним лежат другие объекты. Нельзя взять и найти там место под еще пару полей, которых в объекте изначально не было.

Максимум - можно пересоздать объект с новым типом, скопировав него все поля. Вручную, через Reflection, или через [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/). Судя по всему, у вас Product - это что-то вроде DTO, который вы получаете извне, так что это будет вполне подходящим решением.

```
PM> Install-Package Automapper
```

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApp30
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string supplierId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pack : Product
    {
        public double width { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product original = new Product()
            {
                id = 4,
                supplierId = "2"
            };

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Product, Pack>();
            });

            Pack pack = Mapper.Map<Product, Pack>(original);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Для случая, когда классу нужно обладать новым свойством - используют template-обвёртки. Т.е. правильно делать так:

```
public class Pack<T> {
  public T item;
  Pack(){
     item = default(T);
     }

  public double width { get; set; }

  private void Method(int val){            
    /*Ну если очень уж хочется взять продукт внутри, можно так, но лучше снаружи*/
    if (item is Product)  /*Если T не продукт - может не собраться - поэтому два каста */
        item = ((Product)(object)Class2.GetProduct(val));
    this.width = 0.1D;
    }

 // Или лучше сделать так (более правильно)
   Pack(T myobj) {
     item = myobj;
     this.width = 0.1D;   
     }
  }
```

Теперь есть вариант `Pack<Product> item = new Pack<Product>(); item.Method(0);` 
   Или возможно лучше так

```
 Pack item = new Pack(Class2.GetProduct(val)); // Компилятор сам подставит продукт
 item.width = 0.1D;
```

Если понадобился продукт - то к полям продукта обратится так `item.item.supplierId`;

Классы-обвертки чаще всего используют для цели, когда нужно "черный ящик" дополнить новыми свойствами. это удобно для баз-данных, списков, контейнеров.

---

Незнаю зачем нужна задача приведения класса - его нельзя привести, потому что класс А:B не равен классу B.
   Но частично (привести) скопировать можно, допустим через рефлексию.

```
 Product product = Class2.GetProduct(val);

 Pack item = new Pack();
 foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(Product).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
     pi.SetValue(item, pi.GetValue(item,null),null);
 item.width = 0.1D;
```

Возможно так же нужно будет скопировать поля (Fields) аналогично, но для даного случая не нужно.
  Рефлексия считается дурным тоном, и такая реализация считается нарушением концепции ООП.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74136/discussion-between-grundy-and-nick-n-a).